# Windows 11 - Various .exe files closing themselves after execution

Tags: windows-update, windows-11, trojan, microsoft

I'm running a system that runs Windows 11. The issue is, that whenever I open certain programs, they open and after 2-10s they close themselves. Between the 2-10s the programs are frozen and don't respond to any keyboard or mouse inputs.
When right clicking the .exe files and running the windows troubleshoot option, it seems to crash too. Both the troubleshooting option and the regular execution of programs seem to crash without any warnings or logs even when run from a console.

This started happening today. There could be two things causing the issue:

1. I updated windows 11 just this morning. I am now on version 22H2.
2. Before the update I tried installing Telegram Desktop from their website (back then I didn't have any issues running programs) but the installation crashed without any error/logs. I then investigated using Kaspersky total security. It did find a probable trojan hidden inside a mod (frosty mod) for Need for speed. I imediately removed every file associated with it and restarted the system.

After restarting I still couldn't install Telegram.
Kaspersky did and still doesn't find anything suspicious either.

After these two probable causes for my issues, I started to encounter the now main problem with windows not keeping my programs running. Before deleting the trojan, trying to install Telegram and updating windows these issues were not present.

**Affected programs:**

- Visual studio code insiders and regular
- Filezilla
- Telegram
- Postman
- Probably many more (untested)

**Not affected programs:**

- Microsoft office apps
- Chrome
- Spotify / soundcloud
- CMD and any other system executables
- Antivirus software (Kaspersky)

How do I best fix this and be sure it's not a trojan behind all of this?

I hope it's clear what my situation is and if you need any log files/system information just ask. Thanks

Comment: This is not any kind if Windows 11 issue.  Scan live and offline for viruses.  Check for old, legacy and incompatible software.   Update ALL drivers including BIOS

Comment: I tried scanning Live and offline but couldn't detect any viruses. I also removed any old or outdated software. I can't seem to be able to update my drivers. When using Intel Driver & support assistant (as usual) It asks me for permission (updating drivers) and then just keeps loading without anything happening. I guess it can't install them because it's the same issue as with the closing of .exe files

Comment: Try a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link.  Start with the option to Keep Everything

Comment: Unfortunately the installation Media won't run beacuse it crashes too. Do you have any other suggestions before I backup my data and reinstall windows?

Comment: If repair does not run, you need to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: I was able to fix the error in a last effort. I manually removed all asus software and reinstalled gpu tweak III. Now everything works fine again. It seemed to be a graphical issue.